# Why is Joey's line "I'm surprised you didn't go home wearing it" funny in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I'm watching this clip [Friends: Someone Ate Ross' Sandwich (Season 5 Clip) | TBS](https://youtu.be/AeKizzQpPpY?t=53). At 0:53, Ross hands over a food note to Chandler and Chandler starts to read it (transcript quoted from [here](https://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season5/509uncut.htm)):

> Ross: ... I still can't believe someone ate it!! I mean, look, I left a note and everything.
>
> (Shows the note to Chandler who reads it aloud.)
>
> Chandler: (reading) Knock-knock. Who's there? Ross Geller's lunch. Ross Geller's lunch, who? Ross Geller's lunch, please don't take me. Okay?
>
> Joey: **I'm surprised you didn't go home wearing your lunch.**

After Joey says "I'm surprised you didn't go home wearing your lunch", the entire audience laughs. But **I don't understand why Joey's line is funny.** Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone is 'wearing a meal', it usually means they have food on their clothes, perhaps because they are a messy eater (e.g. a small child), or have had an spillage accident while eating, and some of their food is on their clothes (thus they are 'wearing' it).

Sometimes their meal has been deposited on them, or thrown at them, by an angry person, for example a dinner companion or person they are on a date with. In this case it is suggested that a colleague or room-mate might have been annoyed at the  stupid note. Such messages are a frequent cause of annoyance or amusement, and can lead to retaliation.

[Same question, asked in 2018 on another site](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/im-surprised-you-didnt-go-home-wearing-your-lunch.3492939/)

[Web search shows numerous others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22wearing%20your%20lunch%22)

Comment: In this context, there’s no question: it was the latter meaning. At that point in the series. Ross had increasingly been a bit of a pain in the ass about things. Joey was almost saying that had *he* been one of Ross’s work colleagues, he himself would have emptied the food on him. 

Comment: I had a colleague who told me that when he went to the shared office refrigerator, he always went for the milk that had e.g. "Joe's milk, don't touch" on the grounds that dickheads need to suffer.

Comment: I am sorry to say I followed his example.

Comment: Little bit of green food coloring is what Joe needed there.

Comment: @tkp - then the building services team would throw it out for being spoiled.

Comment: Buildin' services? You were lucky...